# .getRangeList won't return values from a range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script

```
  var data_range = srcSheet.getRangeList(['AK7:BB39','BD7:BD39']); 
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
```

Why won't data_data store the array of the .getRangeList?

Error received is "data_range.getValues is not a function".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
var data_range = srcSheet.getRangeList(['AK7:BB39','BD7:BD39']); 
var data_data = data_range.getValues();
```

Try this:

```
var rgA = srcSheet.getRangeList(['AK7:BB39','BD7:BD39']).getRanges(); 
var data=[];
rgA.forEach(function(rg,i){
  data.push(rg.getValues());
});
```

data is now an array of two dimensional arrays of data.

[Class  RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: Once this is done, could use [data.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to transform it to a 2D array.

Comment: @lamblichus doing so makes it very easy to lose the knowledge of where each value came from. Maybe that's ok, maybe not. Very application-specific.

Comment: If I had more information about the question I would have been inclined to load it into appropriate sheets or whatever is needed within the loop.